# How to send more then one response to client from Netty

Tags: java, netty, tcp

I want to send more than one response to `client` based on back end process. But in `Netty` examples I saw `echo server` is sending back the `response` at the same time.

My requirement is,  I need to validate the client and send him OK response, then send him the `DB` updates when available.

How can I send more `responses` to `client`? Pls direct me to an example or any guide?

Comment: Sure. [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/guide/html/index.html) you go. Maybe read past "Getting Started".

Comment: @Elliott 
you mean I can carry the Channel through my program and use it when ever I want later. Is it?

Comment: I can't answer that. It depends on your protocol.

Comment: @Elliott 
The examples given in the site you gave have used TCP/IP right? If I use the same thing?

Comment: No. Now you're describing the channel. What do you want to communicate? How should it scale? Are you trying to write a web-server? Is this to stream video? etc.

Comment: @Elliott 
My client is sending me XML request and My server respond with XML.

Comment: You and your client must agree on how the XML request will be made, and how the XML response will be returned. That is your protocol. It sounds like your client sends you an XML payload. Do they then close the socket? If so, you can only send one response.

Comment: @Elliott 
No they keep open the socket for my responses. This connection can be last long time. Also there can be more or less 1000 clients for my Server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45762/discussion-between-user2771655-and-elliott-frisch)

Answer (score 1):

at every point in your pipeline you can get the pipeline [Channel](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/Channel.html) object from the [MessageEvent](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/MessageEvent.html) object (or [ChannelEvent](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelEvent.html)) which is passed from handler to handler. you can use this information to send multiple responses at different points in the pipeline.

if we take the echo server example as a base, we can add a handler which send the echo again (that can be done also in the same handler, but the example is to show that multiple handlers can respond).

```
    public class EchoServerHandler extends ChannelHandlerAdapter {

        public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
           Channel ch = e.getChannel();
           // first message
           ch.write(e.getMessage());
        }
        // ...
    }

    public class EchoServerHandler2 extends ChannelHandlerAdapter {

           public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
           Channel ch = e.getChannel();
           // send second message     
           ch.write(e.getMessage());
        }
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as long as you have the reference to the relevant `Channel` (or `ChannelHandlerContext`).  For example, you can do this:

```
public class MyHandler extends ChannelHandlerAdapter {
  ...
  public void channelRead(ctx, msg) {
    MyRequest req = (MyRequest) msg;
    ctx.write(new MyFirstResponse(..));
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // Perform database operation
        ..
        ctx.write(new MySecondResponse(...));
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as long as Netty doesn't close the Channel. Its better you call close() yourself when you're done.

Here's a sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48128514/2557517